# Java Is there an exception about Spring Profile?

Tags: java, spring

when I test Spring profile,I create a class named "student" and add the annotation @Profile("prod") to test create bean.

```
@Component
public class Student{
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public Student(String name,int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  //getter and setter toString()
}
```

java pojo

this is an configuration class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.lucky.profile")
public class ProfileConfig{

  @Bean
  @Profile("prod")
  public Student student(){
    return new Student("jack",12);
  }
}
```

but the bean can't be created,I don't know where is the reason for this question.
I tried to delete the annotation @Profile("prod") in the ProfileConfig.class ,whene I deleted the annotation ,it can be created the bean,but when I add the annotation again ,it was still have this UnsatisfiedDependencyException.

```
@RunWith(SpringJunit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={ProfileConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles("prod")
public class ProfileActiveTest{
    @Test
    public void test1(){
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ProfileConfig.class);
        Student student = ctx.getBean("student");
        System.out.println(student.toString());
    }
}
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'student' defined in file [E:\work_spaces\spring4_workspaces\springInAction\chapter3_a\target\classes\com\lucky\profile\Student.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:758)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:88)
    at com.lucky.profile.ProfileActiveTest.test(ProfileActiveTest.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721)
    ... 44 more
```

how can happen this error?I want someone can help me ?thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `@Component` from the Student class. You already have the bean defined in the `ProfileConfig`.

The reason for the error is that the error, though, is that your class has a constructor that accepts a `String` and an `int`. When Spring tries to instantiate this bean - when it's annotated by `@Component` - it'll try to look up beans to inject via constructor. That's why it says `No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available` in the stacktrace - there is no bean of type `String` available in the context.

When you instantiate your bean yourself, like you do in the `ProfileConfig`, you provide the dependencies yourself.

Here's what worked for me:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class)
@ActiveProfiles("prod")
public class SpringExampleTest {

    @Autowired
    private Student student;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // Just using the bean
        System.out.println(student.getName());

        // Getting it through application context
        System.out.println(((Student)context.getBean("student")).getName());
    }
}


class Student {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Student(final String name, final int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}

@Configuration
class Config {

    @Bean
    @Profile("prod")
    public Student student() {
        return new Student("Andy", 27);
    }
}
```

Note that I don't create a new ApplicationContext, rather I inject one provided by the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`. But even that is not necessary, as you can inject your beans directly, also using `@Autowired`.

Comment: I try to delete the annotation @Componnet in the Student.java ,but another error ocurred.It said no bean named 'student' available.

Comment: Then I update the ProfileConfig.java ,@Bean("student") update the annotation ,but still said No bean named 'student' available.

Comment: And if I delete the configuration of profile ,it will be ok.But add the profile configuration ,it will be throw NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: no bean named 'student' available.

Comment: First of all, I would check the `@ComponentScan("com.lucky.profile")` - if the package is set correctly. It should include the configuration.

Second, I'd try to autowire the Student bean in the test. And avoid creating the Application context - `SpringJunit4ClassRunner.class` should do it for you.

Comment: I've edited my answer and added an example that should help you out. Good luck!